# In ''mysql'' Manager of pid file quit without update file

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-12.04

I am in a serious problem while installing mysql on ubuntu 12.04 32 bit. when i start mysql with command ''./mysql.server start'' I got this error Manager of pid file quit without updating pid file. I installed ''mysql-5.1.39-linux-i686-glibc23''.
I thoroughly search for the solution to fix this error but cannot resolve it yet. I copied my-medium.cnf file to the /etc directory and rename it by my.cnf also edited this file in the section ''The mysql Server'' and add these lines ''datadir = /exports/disk0/data'' but could fix this problem. Can any one help on this.

Answer (score 4):

The message bout the pid file is kind of a red herring. It just means that the init script `/etc/init.d/mysql` did not return success. The root cause could be a variety of things, for example file permissions problems in your datadir, or the config file contained an invalid line, or dozens of other possible problems.

When you get the error about the pid file, the first thing you should do is to go read the MySQL error log file. Usually this is in the data directory, and it may be called `hostname.err` (where "hostname" is the name of the server you installed MySQL).

Search the file for any lines reporting "`ERROR`" and then use Google to research the error.