# Reason behind this error . ERROR! Manager of pid-file quit without updating file. In my sql

Tags: mysql

I am not looking for the workarounds . I eager about knowing what the possible reasons could be

Comment: possible duplicate of [In ''mysql'' Manager of pid file quit without update file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22587780/in-mysql-manager-of-pid-file-quit-without-update-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following found at this link which worked for me: http://www.emreakkas.com/windows-tips/solution-manager-of-pid-file-quit-without-updating-file

If you are getting this error when you try to start mysql server, mysql is having a problem with one of the variables that you have in its configuration file my.cnf.

```
 Manager of pid-file quit without updating file
```

First verify that this is true. Rename my.cnf to my.old.cnf and try starting the server again. If you do not know where my.cnf is, you can do “locate my.cnf”.

If mysql server starts fine when you rename my.cnf, it confirms that it is having a problem with your my.cnf file. Rename the file back to its original name and try starting the server. Once you get the “Manager of pid-file quit without updating file” error message, head to the mysql error log. This error log may be under your system’s log directory (/var/log/mysql) or under the mysql data folder (usually /usr/local/mysql/data). Tail the file to see the problem.